# Alignment in columns

Tags: alignment

I need to stack three objects on top of each other and align the first two to the center and the third one to the left. I've been trying to do this with `Column`, but it won't let me align the objects differently. The code below should make clear what I'm trying to do:

```
Column[{Style["Title", FontSize -> 20, "Title"],Graphics@Disk[],Style["Footnote text..."]}, 
  {Center, Center, Left}]
```

I want the title and the disk to be centered, but the footnotes aligned to the left. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Item` to specify and individual alignment:

```
Column[{
  Style["Title", FontSize -> 20, "Title"],
  Graphics@Disk[],
  Item[Style["Footnote text..."], Alignment -> Left]
  }, 
Alignment -> Center]
```

or use the Alignment specification as per @Oska example. Remember that `Column` is a `GridBox` so also see `Grid` docs for a larger number of options examples.

[image]

```
Column[{
  Style["Title", FontSize -> 20, "Title"],
  Graphics@Disk[],
  Style["Footnote text..."]
  },
 Alignment -> {Center, Center, {{-1, 1} -> Left}}]
```

Comment: That way requires one less word. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can define a `list` of the expressions you want in your `Column` and an other, `listAlign`, of the placement that you wish:

```
list = {Style["Title", FontSize -> 20, "Title"], Graphics@Disk[], Style["Footnote text..."]};
listAlign = {Center, Center, Left};
Panel@Column[list, Alignment -> {{}, {}, 
  Rule @@@ Thread[{{#, 1} & /@ Range@Length@list, listAlign}]}]
```

[image]

Then, working on a bigger list is much easier:

```
list = RandomChoice[{Style["Hello", FontSize -> 20, Bold], 
  Style["Hello"], Style["Hello", Tiny]}, 9]~Join~{"Bye"};
listAlign = RandomChoice[{Left, Center, Right}, 10];
Panel@Column[list, 
  Alignment -> {{}, {}, 
    Rule @@@ Thread[{{#, 1} & /@ Range@Length@list, listAlign}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I see. So separate column every time I want to change the alignment.Thanks

Comment: @Mas check the updated answer, it is now easier :)